# How to add data from ByteArray to linkedlist without using for loop?

Tags: java

Requirement:  Data will continuously come in form of chunks(byteArray) from sensor. When the data comes, I want to add it to an existing LinkedList. Hence the LinkedList will be updated continuously. 
I would like to know if this can be done without using a for loop.

My current code is

```
  public static LinkedList<Byte> ll = new LinkedList<>();
  public void dataStoring(byte[] data){
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      ll.addLast(data[i]);
    }
  }
```

If possible, I want it to be done in one step, without using a for loop.

Note: I want LinkedList instead of list because I want to remove data after certain period.

Comment: I sense a potential concurrency issue in the future. Anyway, is there a reason why you don't want a loop? Would storing a `LinkedList<byte[]>` be acceptable? Would using Stream API be acceptable?

Comment: This question isn't really related to android. It is a common Java question and doesn't depend on android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

**Approach1:**

```
LinkedList<Byte> ll = new LinkedList<>();
public void dataStoring(Byte[] data){
    final List<Byte> list = Arrays.asList(data);
    ll.addAll(list);
}
```

**Approach 2 (Highlighted by TejasW):**

```
 LinkedList<Byte> ll = new LinkedList<>();
 public void dataStoring(Byte[] data) {        
    Collections.addAll(ll, data);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Sagar , I tried to apply above solution. I am getting error : addAll in LinkedList<Byte> can not be applied to LinkedList<Byte[]>. So do this I need to change LinkedList<Byte> to LinkedList<Byte[]>  which I don't want to do . This creates problem while getting data from linkedList. Any other solution?

Comment: Are you creating List first before creating LinkedList as shown in the code in my answer? `public static LinkedList<Byte> ll = new LinkedList<>();`

Comment: Yes <br/> Getting Same error. Can we add List<Byte[ ]>  in to LinkedList<Byte> ? <br/> I dont think so.

Comment: @TejasW its working fine for me. Can you update your question with the code you are trying?

Comment: Hi Sagar , This worked for me .                                                                                           Byte[] dataByte= ArrayUtils.toObject(data);
Collections.addAll(ll,dataByte);                                                                                         Thanks.